# In RXJS : replace an infinite observable by an other each time the first emits

Tags: angular, rxjs, operators, flat

I would like to achieve the same thing than below in a smartest way :

```js
charteringsPassFromZeroToOneEmpty$
  .pipe(
    withLatestFrom(transportFeatures$),
    map(
      ([nothing, transportFeatures]: [
        void,
        Partial<TransportFeatures>
      ]) => transportFeatures
    )
  )
```

Each obervable is made with "valueChange()", in Angular reactive forms.
I have tried sample(), throttle() and switchMap(), nothing is working.
Does anyone has an idea ?

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to achieve. could you please provide more details?

Comment: Yes sorry. I should'nt have so many code. There it is, I have shortened it. This code work but I find it ugly, it's itching me to find a shorter / smarter code.

Comment: The expected result is only the transportFeatures$ last value, each time that charteringsPassFromZeroToOneEmpty$ will be triggered.

Comment: I believe your way is the shortest one, you could omit params typings in map callback in your case, because they can be inferred from the context

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. I am stunnish there is no better way ?

Comment: you want to construct an observable that depends on 2 sources, you use the least possible amount of operators (1 = withLatestFrom) to connect them and map to transform the result. Yes, I am pretty sure this way is the shortest one, otherwise the behavior wouldn't be the same. the only thing you could do is replace map with `pluck(1)` operator, but i am not sure if the types will remain correct

Comment: Ah ok. I didn't know `pluck()`, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) This is the best I can come up with the details provided.

```
combineLatest(charteringsPassFromZeroToOneEmpty$, transportFeatures$, firstCharteringWithfirstLoadingLastDelivery$).pipe(
    filter(
      ([nothing, transportFeatures]: [
        void,
        Partial<TransportFeatures>
      ]) => transportFeatures?.multimodal === false
    ),
    map(
      ([nothing, transportFeatures]: [
        void,
        Partial<TransportFeatures>
      ]) => transportFeatures
    ),
    takeUntil(this._onDestroy$)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. In fact I need that the resulting observable will be trigger only with charteringsPassFromZeroToOneEmpty$. With your solution, it will be trigger with all the combined observables.